# Set Style by Dynamic Actions does not work

Tags: oracle-apex

I would like to change the color of the Display Only text on a form depending on its value. As I read it, I have created a Dynamic Action to set it, but it doesn't work. To test it, I created a second True Action in the same place that sets the value of another item. This works, so the Action fired, but the color did not change. I tried coloring by a static value (f.e. green), but nothing changed. I have an another simple test project where this method works.
The APEX version is 21.1.6

Comment: Do you mind sharing the details of the dynamic action that doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the properties of the display only item in the inspector you'll see that the actual page item has an input tag with attribute "hidden" so it is not displayed. Following the hidden element there is another tag with an element id of item_name_DISPLAY. That is where you want to set the style.

Example:

- Page item "P33_DISPLAY_ONLY" of type "Display Only"
- Dynamic action on change of "P33_DISPLAY"
- True action of type "Execute Javascript" with code

```
$('#P33_DISPLAY_ONLY_DISPLAY').css({ color: "red" });
```

Note the id: it is `P33_DISPLAY_ONLY_DISPLAY` not `P33_DISPLAY_ONLY`

- Add a client-side condition to each true action per color you want to set.